# ObjectDb - JAVA - Error con Key

Tags: java

Me sale este error :

```
Failed to commit transaction: Attempt to reuse an existing primary key value (model.Assignatura:4)
```

me señala esta parte del código:

```
 public void modificar(Assignatura ass) throws GestorException {
        //TODO codificar el metode modificar
         em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(ass);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

no sé que puede estar mal.. 
podéis ayudarme?

Comment: Podrias intentar darle em.flush(); antes del commit

Comment: Si y no es necesario empezar las transacciones como lo estas haciendo el contenedor lo hacer automaticamente

Comment: ooohh!! ya me funciona gracias!!

Comment: ponlo en respuesta para puntuarte! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estas usando `EntityManager` administrado por contenedor de java, el se encarga de las transacciones. Por lo tanto, no es necesario `entityManager.getTransaction ()` y el `em.getTransaction().commit();`.

JTA inicia y confirma su transacción pero si quieres que se haga en al momento de hacer el **insert** se utilice **`em.flush();`** esto equivale a un `commit`, como el que se hace para que se refleje el resultado en la base de datos.